# Silly confusion to prove Curl and divergence of a differentiable vector field.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

*prove that  $curl F=\nabla×F$ and $div F= \nabla.F$ in usual notations* 
**Now I am just lost in the statement as what is there to prove?

For curl , Shall I need to take cross product and show that it is curl? Please tell me how should I write this proof properly**

Comment: Isn't that the definition of curl and divergence?

Comment: Yes of course, so I  am lost that how should I prove this.

Comment: There is no proof for a definition.. Could you maybe post a picture of the source?

Comment: As I  am new here I am not able to post picture. I  am post graduate student and this is asked in question paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe that in your curse the **curl** and **div** operators are defined without the use of the $\vec{\nabla}$ operator. In this case, as example,  the **curl** of a function $\vec F:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3\quad \vec F(\vec x)=\vec F(x,y,z)=A(\vec x)\hat i+B(\vec x)\hat j+C(\vec x)\hat k \;$ is **defined** as:
$$
\mbox {curl} (F)=\left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial B}{\partial z}\right)\hat i +\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}\right)\hat j+\left(\frac{\partial B}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial A}{\partial y}\right)\hat k
$$

so, if we introduce the ''vector'' operator 
$$
\vec{\nabla}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\hat i+\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\hat j+
\frac{\partial }{\partial z}\hat k$$

we can see, by the definition of cross product
$$
\vec V \times \vec W=
\det \begin{bmatrix}
\hat i&\hat j& \hat k\\
V_x&V_y&V_z\\
W_x&W_y&W_z
\end{bmatrix}
$$
 that 
$$
\mbox {curl} (F)=\vec{\nabla}\times \vec F
$$

And analogously for the divergence operator.